# Xamarin Auth IOS simulator Save Account to KeyChain

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, keychain, simulator

I am developing a Cross Platform application using Xamarin Forms my IDE
is Visual Studio Community 2017.

I am using XamarinAuth to authenticate against Google.

The authentication works flawlessly, the issue is this

On Android I can store the RefreshToken using AccountStore, but
on iOS it does NOT store anything to the iOS KeyChain.

I am using a MacMini to run an iOS simulator version 10.3

Do I need to add something to the Entitlement.plist?
Or perhaps the Info.plist?
Or perhaps I need a special Dev certificate from Apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the response guys.... Thank you deepthoughts for the provisioning link.
But I figured this out, the key chain feature from iOS cant be used with the iOS simulator you will need an actual iOS device and it needs to be provisioned properly.

You will need XCODE and the provisioning instructions.

So in a nut shell it is not possible to use the KeyChain feature, to do so
You need;
1. Real iOS device
2. Provision the device properly link provided by deepthroughts(Thank you )
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html
3. XCODE for provisioning.

I hope this helped someone out there.

Good luck everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to declare access to KeyChain using the entitlement.plist. Read up details on the Apple Dev page: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html

Hope this helps!
Cheers